# Необходима помощь в написании функции. Golang

Tags: golang

Написать функцию my_print, которая может принимать на вход произвольное количество аргументов. Аргументы представляют собой натуральные числа. Далее все эти числа должны выводиться, каждое с новой строки.

Comment: Нужно почитать учебник, руководство по языку, хелп, да и написать.

Answer (score 1):

А вы книгу пробовали открывать или хотя бы вот этот пример посмотрите
https://gobyexample.com.ru/variadic-functions